# Malicious object injection with xstream

Tags: java, security, xstream

Can I safely use XStream to process XML coming from outside of my system ?
What's the best practice when dealing with "potentially malicious XML" using xstream ?

Let's say, I have a class somewhere in my code like this :

```
 package hazard;
 class Dangerous {
    public Dangerous() {
       AtomicBomb.getInstance().nuke();
    }
 }
```

A malicious user, might submit a XML file such as :

```
 <hazard.Dangerous/>
```

and make XStream calls the nuke() method.

This example is quite theoretical. As was pointed out, I do not expect constructor to do this kind of things. But can I be certain that no constructor in any lib available in the classpath is free from such issues (for example, allocate some ressource like a file descriptor).

The point is that sending a XML file allows an attacker to create arbitrary objects. A more realistic approach might be using some class instead of another one.

```
public class Foo<T implements Bar> {
    private T t;
    // Getters/setters ...
}

public interface Bar {
   public void bar();
}

public class Bar1 implements Bar {
   // ...
}

public class Bar2 implements Bar {
   // ...
}
```

With the (malicious) XML input :

```
<foo>
  <!-- I expect bar1 -->
  <package.Bar2/>
</foo>
```

Now with the Java code :

```
Bar<Foo1> bar = (Bar<Foo1>) xstream.fromXML(xml);
// I expect to have a bar1 but I have a bar2.
bar.getT().foo();
```

At first glance, the solution is to provide a custom Mapper (the job being done in the realClass() method).

Comment: There is a variety of ways to nuke an Java instance.  For a start I wouldn't allow system to pass arbitrary XML. Just passing a double value of `2.2250738585072012e-308` will kill all but the most recent versions of Java.

Comment: why would you ever call "dangerous" code from an object's constructor?

Comment: I've looked at default Java serialization quite a bit and it's very difficult to do it in a secure way. I gave a quick look at XStream and certainly you're correct to be wary. If you really must get your data from an untrusted source, I suggest whitelisting the classes to some limited set of POJOs, but I don't know how to do that with XStream.

Comment: Most Java core constructors behave well, but not even all of them. And 3rd party libs must be even worse.

Comment: In fact, at least in "enhanced" mode, the constructor is not called at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never ever allow xstream (or any other serialization framework) to marshal anything but clean, pure javabeans (getters and setters).

UPDATE:
Your mentioned theory about using a Mapper should work, although it will require some amount of scaffolding and custom config being built by you. Another way is to use the feature of XStream to specify a dedicated classloader for resolving classes. What you would try is to put all classes that SHOULD be allowed to be marshalled by xstream in a separate JAR (think of it as a domain module). Then create a clean classloader that only loads that JAR and assign it to xstream. That way, xstream will not know of any classes outside of it's scope, failing to deserialize anything you don't want it to.

Try something like

```
ClassLoader bootstrapClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent();
List urls = new ArrayList();
urls.add(new File("yourJarOfXstreamBeanClasses.jar").toURL());
ClassLoader xstreamClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[0]), bootstrapClassLoader);
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.setClassLoader(xstreamClassLoader);
```

Comment: Indeed, but the question is "How can/should I prevent XStream from instanciaing unexpected classes from malicious XML ?"

Comment: Indeed, it is quite a lot of work. I feel that JAXB is more suitable for this.

Answer (score -1):

What if someone on your development team calls `DangerousClass()`? XStream is going to persist the object, if you are reading this in and the XML has changed, you will receive at best a ClassCastException.

Try changing the structure of your class and then read in using XStream, you will get errors. If you persist parameters which will be used in a DB query, make sure you use prepared statements. If you put code in an objects constructor that could damage a system, that is your bad coding practice. Use your constructor for initializing values, not calling code, that is what methods are for.

If you code properly there should be no security risks associated with XStream.